# Bad 'cp' command?

Tags: android, command, kernel, rom

In my AndroidBoard.mk I have this line

```
# device.mk doesn't know about us, and we can't PRODUCT_COPY_FILES here.
# So cp will do.

.PHONY: $(PRODUCT_OUT)/kernel
        $(PRODUCT_OUT)/kernel: $(TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL)
          cp $(TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL) $(PRODUCT_OUT)/kernel
```

But the terminal gives me this error:

`cp  out/target/product/w7/kernel
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘out/target/product/w7/kernel’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
make: *** [out/target/product/w7/kernel] Error 1`

What's wrong with it? :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL is not defined.

Since it is empty, cp command is receiving only one attribute (in other words, it is missing destination file operand)

I don't believe that "$(PRODUCT_OUT)/kernel" is empty because log is printing "out/target/product/w7/kernel"

So, PRODUCT_OUT seems defined.

Comment: So, I should do something like this:

`TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL=/directory/of/kernel`

Before the cp command is written?

Comment: I woud try that or you shoud search where it is defined and check why it is not being defined